# css resize property - change resize icon properties

Tags: css, resize

I have a div with the 'resize' property. By default, you can only change the size by dragging the window's bottom-right corner. I would like to know if it's possible to change the behavior of this at all, such as its **appearance**, **size**, or **position**.

Specifically what I would like to do is allow the user to re-size the window on the edge (rather than the corner), similar to a OS window (preferably on only one side) in css.

[image: Example]

Comment: I am looking for a css only solution, and would really like to not see "I know you only asked for css, but..." answers. You can post them, but they will not help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you want? I understand you want to resize and you got that working, you want to change position by dragging? and what about the appearance? Changing the position by dragging is as far as i kno not possible with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with standard css. The resizer widget, like scrollbars, is typically from OS. You *may* be able to style it with custom browser selectors, however, that depends on the browser. Webkit you can do some limited styling by using the `::-webkit-resizer` selector.

```
#somediv {
    resize: both;
}

#somediv::-webkit-resizer {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But you cannot adjust its width as far as I can tell.

Comment: your webkit prefix is wrong, it should be `#somediv::-webkit-resizer`

Comment: That's a shame :( Guess I'll have to look into custom selectors then, if I really need.

Comment: Honestly you'd be better off coming up with a JavaScript solution. A lot less pain maintaining it across browsers.

Comment: I believe that webkit has dropped support of this feature since this was posted.