# Hiding resize handle icon in CSS

Tags: css, html-table, resize, responsive

For example I have some kind of table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><div>Title1</div></th>
        <th><div>Title2</div></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div>Body1</div></td>
        <td><div>Body2</div></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I want every `th` column be resizeable, so I add some CSS:

```
th > div {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Everything working fine, every column can be resized horizontally. 
Problem is that in every `<th>` I have an icon for resizing. I want it to be hidden. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: try `th > div, td > div` - your current selector is all `th` and all `div` inside `td`.  Or if you don't want the `th div` to be resizeable, just remove the `th` from your selector

Comment: Is that the resize icon, or some other button?

Comment: It is resize icon which added by browser. You can see such icon in textarea also.

Comment: But if you make an element resizeable, it needs that icon to show it's resizable and where to drag, otherwise how would a user know that it is resizeable?

Comment: I want instead of resize icon, add special cursor icon on hovering the right border

Comment: You should add that information in your question as well, are there any other doubts, please add.

Comment: I think you would need to write your own js resizer plugin then as using the standard css will always give you the default resize icon - I don't think there is currently a way to change that

Comment: @Genjik - I've added a solution that covers a few more of your requirements - namely that all cells are resizeable, _and_ a custom cursor when the right border is hovered.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to remove the icon from each and every `td` just use `th > div` selector.

See the example below:

If you want to play with that resize icon: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777504/css-resize-property-change-resize-icon-properties)

```css
th > div{
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><div>Title1</div></th>
        <th><div>Title2</div></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div>Body1</div></td>
        <td><div>Body2</div></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11):

Here are three possible solutions:

1. Use the `::webkit-resizer` psuedo selector to style the resizer
2. Use a `:after` psuedo element to 'hide' the resizer (and add a custom cursor)
3. Use the `:hover` psuedo class to add the `resize` only on `:hover`

---

**1.** It's not cross-browser compliant, but might work for you - the `::-webkit-resizer` selector. This allows some basic control over the styling of the resizer icon. We can make it transparent with the following:

(this will only work in Safari)

```css
th > div,
td > div {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}

td > div::-webkit-resizer {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<strong>The `::-webkit-resizer` selector only works in Safari</strong>

<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><div>Title1</div></th>
        <th><div>Title2</div></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div>Body1</div></td>
        <td><div>Body2</div></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

**2.** As a more cross-browser solution, we can 'hide' the resizer icon behind a `:after` psuedo element. The idea here is to create an `:after` element that sits in the bottom-right corner of the `td > div` elements (on top of the resizer icon) with a background color that matches the table cell background color. The only remaining change is to add a small amount of padding to the right-side of the cells so the `:after` psuedo element doesn't also cover the cell contents.

The main advantage of this option is we can add the custom cursor you mentioned you wanted. Using the `td > div:hover:after` selector we can apply a cursor when the right-side of the resizable table cells is on `:hover`. Like this:

Like this:

```css
th > div,
td > div {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 8px 0 0;
  min-width: 45px;
}

td > div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
}

td > div:hover:after {
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>Title1</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>Title2</div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Body1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Body2</div>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

**3.** If we want the cells to be resizable, hide the resize element, and make it obvious the elements are resizable, we can use the `:hover` psuedo class.

Through some experimenting I found this solution works best if you use both `:hover` and `:active` pseudo classes, or the handle on the resize is lost if the cursor is dragged too quickly.

```css
th > div {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}

td > div {
    padding-right: 10px;
    min-width: 40px;
}

td > div:hover,
td > div:active {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<strong>The `::-webkit-resizer` selector only works in Safari</strong>

<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><div>Title1</div></th>
        <th><div>Title2</div></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div>Body1</div></td>
        <td><div>Body2</div></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah now you added the cursor, it woks fine, I was trying to use the space you covered

Comment: It worked without the custom cursor, it just wasn't obvious it was possible.

Comment: 3rd solution is pretty nice!