CSS - hiding resize handle on resizable element
I have a resizable element, for which some browsers render one style of the resize "handle", other browsers a different style and some… well, one browser (yes, looking at you Apple) doesn't render it at all these days. In order to provide consistent styling and visual clue that the element is resizable I can add my own graphics for that handle. This renders nicely and consistently on all browsers. The problem is that "original" handle is still there on browsers, which happen to include their own. I'd like to make it disappear and I found similar older questions, also including answers that might have worked at the time, like
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100141/2428025
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11777737/2428025

"covering" the handle with an :after pseudo element

that no longer (?) works or

the ::webkit-resizer

that still works, albeit not on Firefox
https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_-webkit-resizer
So I am still looking for a cross-browser solution that would work in 2024.

Resizers are OS specific. Currently there is no way in Firefox to style the resizer. You could use a pseudo element but it is still hard to match the size of the actuall resizer since its width is adjusted in JS by the browser. As shown below, it breaks easily by reducing a huge amount of zoom level in Firefox, and you still need to account for it covering actual contents in the resizable div:


.custom-resize{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.resize-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.resize-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
<div class="resize-wrapper">
  <div class="custom-resize">Resize me ...</div>
</div>




If you want a consistance solution I'll suggest you implement a custom resizer using JS instead of using the native CSS resize, or check out third party libraries such as the JQuery Resizable Widget.

I don't think they are "OS specific" - I have four different results on one OS so it's "browser specific" IMHO. As for "custom resizer", it is easy enough to do it in pure JS these days but I would very much prefer not to add JS code to reinvent what HTML/CSS provides anyway. Shall resort to it as the last option in absence of anything JS free.

I said OS specific because as far as I know its the OS that is deciding the look of those UI components. Not exactly sure about that though.

Either way, there was ::moz-resizer but isn't working anymore so you pretty much need to hide it by covering it with other elements. It is maybe possible to avoid JS but you will need a very dedicated CSS to avoid it covering actual contents like I mentioned. Need to also account for when the container is resized to be super small. That's why I recommend might as well just right your own resizer components using something like drag drop events which shouldn't be too hard.

The "super small" is one of the quirks I had to keep eye on with JS  (yes, I wrote handler even before asking the question here) - no immediate way of having individual minimal size of resizable elements. Had to fetch computedStyle and convert it for use in the handler. With CSS the minimum width/height prevents browsers from resizing too small - another thing, which is already there. Thank you regardless. BTW I see that you made the ::after work somehow, although you're fully right that zooming out can break it easily

Resizers work on only their specific os.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
